# modelForm got an unexpected argument 'initial'

Tags: django, modelform, django-errors

modelForm got an unexpected argument 'initial' I am getting this error. please can anyone explain how to solve this ?
Here is my model.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
      StudentID = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=False, unique=True)
      Branch = models.CharField(max_length=255,choices=Departments,default="CSE")

     def __str__(self):
          return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

class complaintForm(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255,choices=complaints,default='Mess')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='complaint_pics/')


   def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

form.py

```
class complaintForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = complaintForm
        fields = ['title','content','image',]
```

views.py

```
class CreateComplaintView(CreateView):
    model = complaintForm
    form_class = complaintForm
    template_name = 'user/post_complaint.html'
    success_url = 'success'
```

Comment: You passed your model as a form. This is why `ComplaintForm` is not a good idea for a model name.

Answer (score 1):

You passed your model to the `form` attribute. This is why `ComplaintForm` is not a good idea for a model name. You better rename this to `Complaint` for example:

```
class Complaint(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255,choices=complaints,default='Mess')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='complaint_pics/')


   def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

You will need to construct and run migrations to rename the table at the database side.

Then you thus define your form as:

```
from app.models import Complaint

class ComplaintForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Complaint
        fields = ['title','content','image',]
```

Finally in your `CreateView`, you can use:

```
from app.models import Complaint
from app.forms import ComplaintForm

class CreateComplaintView(CreateView):
    model = Complaint
    form_class = ComplaintForm
    template_name = 'user/post_complaint.html'
    success_url = 'success'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user.profile
        super().form_valid(form)
```

> **Note**: normally a Django models, just like all classes in Python are given a name in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*, so it should be: `Complaint` instead of <s>`complaint`</s>.

Comment: sir thank you ,  but i have one another doubt . In views.py how can we handle image field ? form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,request.FILES) , In this case we used request.files then form.save(). How can we do it in myviews.py?

Comment: @be18103089GurpreetSingh: that is handled by the `CreateView` already: it will construct a form with `request.POST` and `request.FILES`, and save the form.

Comment: now when i try to fill the form , I am getting this error "no such column: user_complaint.user_id" . I didn't even included user_id in my model

Comment: @be18103089GurpreetSingh: that is because you did not migrate your database properly, or because you `Complaint` model has no `user` field.

Comment: class complaint(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 category = models.CharField(max_length=255,choices=complaints,default='Mess')
 title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 content = models.TextField()
 image = models.ImageField(upload_to='complaint_pics/',blank=True)

 def __str__(self):
  return self.title

Comment: user is foreign key field

Comment: @be18103089GurpreetSingh: and you constructed migrations and migrate the database (so `makemigrations` and `migrate`)?

Comment: @be18103089GurpreetSingh: well the "no such column" means that the ORM and the database on which you work are *not* in sync, hence the ORM assumes there is a column `user_id`, whereas for that database, there is no column.